# Android could scan any barcode type?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

Is any Android mobile / handset / tablet able to scan both 1D and 2D barcode?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, which this does not appear to be.

Comment: Also please do some research before asking anywhere. This is well documented. Don't be lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The android platform does not natively support scanning barcodes of any type.

Third parties have made applications that are capable of scanning all types of codes.

Check out this page: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ for one of the most popular scanning apps. Which also allows other developers to tie into their scanner in their own applications.